# Is it possible to check if a certain line of the file is empty?

Tags: c#, file, if-statement, line

I want to check if a certain line of a file is empty, and if it is, do something.

```
if(File.ReadLines("MainSave.txt").Skip(1).First() == null)
{
      // do something
}
```

Comment: If it's empty, it wouldn't be null, it would be `string.Empty`

Comment: It's not going to be null, either check its length or use `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` on it if it might have whitespace.

Comment: @LarsTech I've tried if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(File.ReadLines("MainSave.txt").Skip(1).First())) but when the if statement is executed, it sill gives the error "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no elements'"

Comment: That's a different error.  You are looking at the wrong file.  Use the full path on `MainSave.txt`.

Comment: Used the full path, still same error.

Comment: Then you don't have anything after the first line.  It's not empty, it doesn't exist.

Comment: Found the answer on another question posted here. .First() needed to be changed to .FirstOrDefault(). Thanks for the help.

Comment: Except if you have stuff on line 1 and line 3, line 2, which you are trying to read, won't be null.